# IncompatibleWorkflowDefinition when canceling the workflow execution

Tags: amazon-swf

I am testing cancel workflow logic with flow library. The code cancel the workflow within the decider code but it throws IncompatibleWorkflowDefinition

```
com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.IncompatibleWorkflowDefinition: Unknown DecisionId [type=EXTERNAL_WORKFLOW, id=735]The possible causes are nondeterministic workflow definition code or incompatible change in the workflow defini
tion.
```

I don't understand why it breaks the logic. Can someone explain why it makes the workflow nondeterministic? Code is like below

```
@Override
  public void dosomething(final Input input) {
      checkInput();
      cancelCurrentWorkflow();
      asyncMethod();
  }
 private cancelCurrentWorkflow() { contextProvider.getDecisionContext().getWorkflowClient().requestCancelWorkflowExecution(contextProvider.getDecisionContext().getWorkflowContext().getWorkflowExecution());}
 @Asynchronous
 asyncMethod()
```

Answer (score 1):

Workflow cancelling itself doesn't make sense. It is usually an operation invoked from the outside using the SWF [requestCancelWorkflowExecution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/AmazonSimpleWorkflow.html#requestCancelWorkflowExecution-com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.model.RequestCancelWorkflowExecutionRequest-) API.

If you need to cancel certain part of the workflow code use [TryCatchFinally](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/core/TryCatchFinally.html).cancel method.

BTW. Are you aware about [Cadence Workflow](http://cadenceworkflow.io) which is an open source reincarnation of SWF? It has much more developer friendly [Java client](https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/06_javaclient/) that doesn't use code generation and AspectJ. It also allows write blocking synchronous code inside the workflow.

Comment: In some scenario you do want to cancel the workflow. The code example above is just for testing. I have more complicated code which calls downstream services and want to cancel the workflow if the downstream service encouter grand failures.
I agree the java client is a pain for the development thus I have plan to move to step function to make my service in a serverless style. Does cadence support serverless  functionality as well?

Comment: Just let an exception from a downstream service propagate without handling it and it is going to cancel all the other activities in the currently running workflow. Cancellation by definition is a request to cancel workflow from the outside.